# How to show div class "article_post_body" on first post only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

First off, the blog layout I'm attempting to edit: [removed]

As titled I'm wanting to display the post text, title etc ("article_post_body") for only the first post of the page, resulting in the posts grid below consisting of only the thumbnail.

I'm able to simply hide the element altogether using css:

`.article_post_body {display:none;}`

However various attempts to apply this to only the first post have been unsuccessful, for example utilizing `<b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'>`within the #Blog1 widget or applying css selectors such as `:first-child`.

Let me know if I've missed out any information that would be useful, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the relevant code within the question body. It is good to provide [a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you'll need for the css:

```
.article_post_body {display: none;}
.col:first-child .article_post_body {display: block;}
```

The first line will hide all the article_post_body, while the second line will show only the first child's article_post_body.

If you look at the current css, you have this css that controls the layout for the first post:

```
.col:first-child {padding: 1% 0 5% 20%; width: 80%;}
```

gl.